# Upload image to Home/Web server VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, upload

I currently upload everything to my web server using FTPWebRequest. I use ZFTP on my server and pay 1999.00 per year for a license. ZFTP is very buggy so I have been trying other methods of uploading images to my web server. So far I have not had any success and trust me, it isn't for lack of trying. Pretty much all I am trying to do is upload an image from my computer to my Home/Web server the same way I do with FTPWebRequest but want to use HTTPWebRequest or something similar. Below are 4 of my attempts though I have attempted everything in the MSDN and converted some C# samples to VB all with no luck.

```
Public Sub LoadImage()
        'Try1
        Dim client As New System.Net.WebClient
        Dim uriString As New System.Uri("http://XXXXXXXXXXXX/cart.png")
        client.UploadFileAsync(uriString, "C:\Users\dstrange\Pictures\add_to_cart.png")

        'Try 2
        Try
            My.Computer.Network.UploadFile("C:\Users\dstrange\Pictures\add_to_cart.png", "http://XXXXXXXXXXXX/img.png", "tyjacobs", "", True, 500)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

        'Try 4
        My.Computer.Network.UploadFile("C:\Users\dstrange\Pictures\add_to_cart.png", "http://XXXXXXXXXXX/somefile.png", "tyjacobs", "")


        'Try 3
        Dim fileToUpload As String = "C:\Users\dstrange\Pictures\add_to_cart.png"
        Dim fileLength As Long = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(fileToUpload).Length

        Dim url As String = "http://XXXXXXXXXXX/img"
        Dim port As String = "443"

        If port <> "" Then

            Dim u As New Uri(url)

            Dim host As String = u.Host

            url = url.Replace(host, host & ":" & port)
            url = url.TrimEnd("/"c) & "/" & IO.Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload)

            Dim userName As String = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
            Dim password As String = "XXXXXXXX"

            request = DirectCast(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)

            request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(userName, password)

            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Put

            request.ContentLength = fileLength

            request.SendChunked = True
            request.Headers.Add("Translate: f")
            request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = True

            Dim s As IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()

            Dim fs As New IO.FileStream(fileToUpload, IO.FileMode.Open, _
                            IO.FileAccess.Read)

            Dim byteTransferRate As Integer = 1024
            Dim bytes(byteTransferRate - 1) As Byte
            Dim bytesRead As Integer = 0
            totalBytesRead = 0

            Do

                bytesRead = fs.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)

                If bytesRead > 0 Then

                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead

                    s.Write(bytes, 0, bytesRead)

                End If

            Loop While bytesRead > 0

            s.Close()
            s.Dispose()
            s = Nothing

            'Close the file
            fs.Close()
            fs.Dispose()
            fs = Nothing


        End If
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim code As HttpStatusCode = response.StatusCode

        'Close the response
        response.Close()
        response = Nothing

        If totalBytesRead = fileLength AndAlso _
            code = HttpStatusCode.Created Then

            MessageBox.Show("The file has uploaded successfully!", "Upload Complete", _
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("The file did not upload successfully.", _
                "Upload Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)

        End If


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP Post Files](http://codepulse.blogspot.com/2010/04/posting-files-to-via-httpwebrequest-in.html) Here is an article that covers the basics.

Comment: This has to be built into an application. I know filezilla server and client are free but that is not the solution to my problem.

Comment: I already use FTPWebRequest for uploading. I do not want to do FTP Uploading. I am needing to do this using HttpWebrequest.